# Cannot get requestWhenInUseAuthorization or requestWhenInUseAuthorization to work

Tags: xcode6

This is my code, it works fine in IOS7 but in IOS8 I can't get authorisation alert to show. I already added the keys in the Info plist for NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription & NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription.

.h

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *LatitudeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *LongitudeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *GPSAccuracyLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *AltitudeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *VerticalAccuracyLabel;

- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

// create a property to hold current time.
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *lastUpdateTime;
@end

@implementation ViewController {
CLLocationManager *locationManager;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.lastUpdateTime = [NSDate date];

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

CLAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus= [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

if (authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways ||
    authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if you need "WhenInUseAuthorization"  in your viewDidLoad :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

self.lastUpdateTime = [NSDate date];

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

CLAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus= [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

NSLog(@"authStatus = %d",authorizationStatus);

if([locationManger respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])

  [locationManger requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];






}
```

Check your status from authStatus

```
typedef enum {
    kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined  = 0,
    kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted ,
    kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied ,
    kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized ,
    kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways  = kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized ,
    kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse
} CLAuthorizationStatus;
```

And remember to add in your info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message</string>
```

Comment: Thanks but I did try this before but also not working, with this code I get warning "Unused variable 'authorizationStatus'?

Comment: Please first make clean your project, uninstall from simulator or your device  and check authStatus

Comment: I did clean & uninstalled from simulator but still no go, I know it's the authorisation as it works in IOS7, I have added the 2 keys & description in Info.plist but notice the word "String" under the "Type" column in both keys are darker text that all the other entries, does this mean anything? authStatus = 0

Comment: please paste your info.plist

Comment: Had to post it as an answer! Above

Comment: I notice NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription is not in the drop menu, maybe this is why it's a darker text?

Comment: ok the plist is correct, try to remove and add"Corelocation Framework" ( when you choose  Corelocation check if is  under iOS 8 folder ).

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I removed & added it, it's under ios8.1 folder, still authStatus = 0. CoreLocation & UIKit is all I need right?

Comment: I found the problem ! In your project you have 2 info.plist, this is the "test" plist, find the other plist and add the   :<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message</string>

Comment: OMG, thanks you so much, I have been at this for a week. How did you know it was the test? Anyway, it finally works. Thanks again.

Comment: Now I have another issue, when I press the button it now updated ok but only once, if I press again nothing happens.

Comment: it's correct ! , you need to set only one time , check authStatus if it is correct

Comment: But before It would update the location each time I press my "Get Location" button, now the button only works once, I have to close app & restart it if I want an update. authStats = 3

Answer (score 0):

This is my Info.Plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.nicoll55.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>BNDL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Required to update your location in the background.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Required to obtain your location.</string>
<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
<false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```